# VisualVM launcher error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, profiling

I'm trying to use the Eclipse VisualVM [launcher](http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html). It seems pretty nice, except that it seems to spawn an instance if VisualVM too late to do any profiling of my application. My application finishes execution before the profiler is even initialized; once it starts up, an error window pops up, saying: `cannot open requested application`. It then shows VM running Eclipse (labeled "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main"). How can I get it to wait for my application and do proper profiling?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know that problem. The only poor man's solution I always came up with is:

1. Set a breakpoint in your source code
2. Start your program in debug mode
3. Connect the profiler
4. Let the program continue

It just takes a bit time for VisualVM to inject the profiling agent into your VM and I am pretty sure that it allows only remote profiling.

As an alternative you could use [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/), it can profile your application from the very start. This way the profiling agent is injected on VM startup:

```
java -agentpath:c:\yourkit\yjpagent.dll FooClass
```

I am curious why VisualVM does not offer this option, since its technically possible. Anyway I think the debug trick is a good solution from within Eclipse, unless you are also interested in the class loading etc.

Comment: Couldn't you just Thread.sleep() while it's working itself out?

Comment: @RyanAmos That's also possible, I have done this before I came over the trick with Debug Mode. I didn't like to time it together with `Timer.sleep`, either your have to wait until `sleep` wears off or the attaching does take too long.

Comment: YourKit is too expensive. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NateGlenn For commerical use you mean?

Comment: For the current problem, yeah. I do need a profiler for academic occasions as well.

Comment: Thank you! The cost of setting a simple breakpoint is very worthwhile :-)

Answer (score 17):

This is probably too late, but I had the same problem, and setting a breakpoint and then starting in debugging mode didn't help at all. I eventually found out that VisualVM saves its temporary data in the folder %TMP%/hsperfdata_[username], on my Windows machine that folder was C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_Jacob for instance. It turned out that the process did not have sufficient permissions to access that folder, so I relaxed the permissions on it and now it works just fine. Hope this is useful for someone having the same problem!

Comment: In my case I was on Windows 10 and my user name contained capital letters that were not represented in hsperfdata. After renaming the folder with the correct user name, everything worked.

Comment: outstanding, thx

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, run Eclipse as Administrator.

Comment: This worked great for me on Windows 8.  Thanks Andres!

Comment: what about eclipse on macOS ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb solution, but works. Here it goes:

Add an infinite loop wrapper to your application, say "while(true) { your_app }".

The timing noises will also even out as your program runs longer.