# Unable to run VisualVM with Intellij or commandline

Tags: java, visualvm

I downloaded visualvm 2.0.6 (currently latest) on windows.
I tried making the following attempts:

### Integrating VisualVM with Intellij IDEA.

1. I installed [VisualVM Launcher](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7115-visualvm-launcher) plugin.
2. Set the VisualVM executable path `bin/visualvm.exe`

- **Executing Run**

1. VisualVM window opens up.
2. My program completed execution.
3. VisualVm shows this error: `can not open requested application`
4. Tried all solutions from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891969/visualvm-launcher-error).

- **Executing Debug**

1. VisualVM window opens up.
2. I can see my application inside the Application node.
3. Visualvm freezes completely and I cannot click/open my application to profile it. I had to end the task from the task manager.

### Commandline way

After seeing no results from above, I tried to run my application normally using the command line.

1. Opened `visualvm.exe`.
2. Opened cmd, and executed the regular java command:

   ```
   java -classpath "path/to/all/jars/dependencies/" main.Main
   ```
3. Program completed execution, but visualvm didn't show anything.

### Other solutions from StackOverflow posts:

All the following didn't work:

- Gave full access to folder `%temp%/hsperfdata_<username>`. [[post]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337342/8520798)
- Deleted `%temp%/hsperfdata_<username>` and closed all java applications, restarted VisualVM (which recreated the `hsperfdata` folder), and tried again. [[post]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167505/8520798)
- Explicitly tried to set the `java.io.tmpdir` while running VisualVm. [[post]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298111/8520798)

  ```
  visualvm -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=[path/to/hsperfdata_<username>]
  ```
- Tried opening Intellij & cmd as administrators and run visualvm. [[post]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18188086/8520798)

---

Is there any step/process I am missing?
If any more information is required, let me know.
Shall I try any other open-source alternative for `VisualVM`?

Comment: Does visualvm run with the exact same JVM as your program?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i only have JDK 13 installed.